# How to add exist image to simple product by REST API

Tags: magento2, api, image

My case is:

I'm creating a `configurable product` by API <-- in this proces I'm adding a new image by:

```
                var newImage = new CatalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1CreatePostBody();
                newImage.entry.label = image.FileName.RemoveAfterLast(".");
                newImage.entry.disabled = false;
                newImage.entry.media_type = "image";
                newImage.entry.position = image.Order.HasValue ? image.Order.Value : index;
                newImage.entry.types = new List<string>() { "image", "small_image", "thumbnail", "swatch_image" };
                newImage.entry.file = "/" + image.FileName[0] + "/" + image.FileName[1] + "/" + image.FileName;
                newImage.entry.content.base64_encoded_data = Convert.ToBase64String(image.FileContent, 0, image.FileContent.Length);
                newImage.entry.content.type = GetMimeType(image.FileName.RemoveBeforeFirst("."));
                newImage.entry.content.name = image.FileName;
                var newImageId = _restRepository.CreateProductImage(product.sku, newImage);
```

then in the different place of code I want to create a `simple products` with added earlier image. I have all information, but without `base64`. While I'm adding a image by:

```
        var productImage = new REST.JsonObject.Request.CatalogProductRepositoryV1SavePostBody.MediaGalleryEntries();
        productImage.id = image.id;
                productImage.media_type = image.media_type;
                productImage.label = image.label;
                productImage.disabled = image.disabled;
                productImage.position = image.position;
                productImage.types = image.types;
                productImage.file = image.file;
                productImage.content = new REST.JsonObject.Request.CatalogProductRepositoryV1SavePostBody.Content();
                productImage.content.type = GetMimeType(image.file.RemoveBeforeLast("/").RemoveBeforeFirst("."));
                productImage.content.name = image.file.RemoveBeforeLast("/");
                product.media_gallery_entries.Add(productImage);
```

I receive
`{"message":"The image content must be valid base64 encoded data."}`

How to add EXIST image in magento to product without sending `image file` every time.

Magento ver. 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

So the problem has been there since a while already. There is a existing plugin, which can solve this issue, but you have to do some manual work on it.

https://github.com/olivertar/m2_api_product_images

You can basically install this plugin. There is a Issue on that Github, where another person already posted the solution but it's not added to the code yet. With that additional change, it works like a charm.